# Overlay a sibling box while respecting parent box

Tags: css, css-position

I'm thinking this isn't possible, but I'm not a CSS expert, so I thought I'd check.  I've got a translucent div absolutely positioned over an image.  That's good so far, but I'd like to force my translucent div to respect the box in which it and the image are contained.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="title-bar"> /* prolly not important */
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </div>
  <img src="whatever"/>
  <div class="overlay">
    A few lines of txt
  </div>
</div>
```

The more I think about it, the more I think I may be asking for too much - I want the parent to expand with the img, but the overlay to be constrained by the parent.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To force the container expand with the child `img`, make it `float`.
To force the overlay relate to container position and size, make the container `relative`.

```
.parent {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

To force the overlay respect the bounds of the container, use percents.

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 100%;
    /* And then, position it at will */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

I've prepared an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rYnVL/

Answer (score 1):

It's  [doable, but not quite beautiful](http://jsfiddle.net/G43tb/1/) :

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="abs">stuff fadsfasd fsad fasdsdaf </div>
    <img src="/img/logo.png" />
</div>

#parent {width:auto; height:auto; border:1px solid blue; background-color:grey;position:relative; display:block;float:left;}

#abs {position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;background:#ff0000;opacity:0.4;}
```

Main point to note :
`parent` floats to not have a 100% width. Position is relative.
`abs` is absolute, with 100% size.

also, if `abs` content is bigger than the image, it will overflow. If you do not like this, just add `overflow:hidden`.